# Why doesn't equality involving "mod" not typecheck in Idris?

Tags: dependent-type, idris

Why won't the following typecheck:

```
v1 : mod 3 2 = 1
v1 = Refl
```

Yet this will typecheck fine:

```
v2 : 3 - 2 = 1
v2 = Refl
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens due to partiality of `mod` function (thanks to [@AntonTrunov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2747511/anton-trunov) clarification). It's polymorphic and by default numeral constants are `Integer`s.

```
Idris> :t mod
mod : Integral ty => ty -> ty -> ty
Idris> :t 3
3 : Integer
Idris> :t mod 3 2
mod 3 2 : Integer
```

For `Integer` type `mod` function is not total.

Instead use [`modNatNZ`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/d9e3a207406367ff75408f0b8bf5fbc94c60ea28/libs/prelude/Prelude/Nat.idr#L329) function so everything type checks perfectly and works.

```
v1 : modNatNZ 3 2 SIsNotZ = 1
v1 = Refl
```

Comment: I'm afraid the statement "on compiler stage Idris can perform only pattern matching in types" is not right. Take, for instance, `(the Int 3) - 2 = 1` you can prove it using `Refl`, although `Int` is not an inductive datatype. The reason `Refl` does not work with `mod` is partiality, as you have already explained.